# JQuery - Unlink draggable element from its scrollable area

Tags: html, jquery, css, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I am implementing a drag-drop functionality where there is a scrollable div container (like a bottom bar) containing the elements (divs) that must be dragged to an area above the original container.

[image: drag unliked from scrollable area]

However, when I drag and drop any of the elements in the drop area, this element remains "associated" with the scrolling area, because if I scroll left or right the bottom bar, the element follows and changes its position in the drop area. As if it were still on the bottom bar.

JQuery

```
$('#home .scroll_carrossel .nav-container .personBtn').draggable({
    distance: 0,        
    drag: function(e, ui) {},
    revert: function(dropped) {
        var dropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "dropped";    
        if(!dropped) {
            for(var i=0; i < qtdObj; i++) {
                posicao(this,'obj'+(i+1), 0,  0 );
                if(i > 0){
                    posicao(this,'obj'+(i+1), 0,  i*56.3 ); 
                }
            }     
        }
        return !dropped;
    } 
});

$('#home .droppable').droppable({
    accept: '.personBtn',
    tolerance: 'intersect',         
    over: function(event, ui) {
        var dragId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        $('.personBtn.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('backing').addClass('dropping').css("z-index", 10);
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        var dragId = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        $('.personBtn.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('dropping').addClass('backing');
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.personBtn.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('dropping').css("z-index", 0);           
    }
}); 

function posicao(tag, objeto, top, left){
    if($(tag).attr('id') == objeto){
        $(tag).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
            top: top, left: left
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id='home'>
    <div class="droppable" id="dropped"></div>
    <div id="lefty"></div>
    <div class='scroll_carrossel'>
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div class="personBtn" id="obj1" ></div>
            <div class="personBtn" id="obj2" ></div>
            <div class="personBtn" id="obj3" ></div>
            <div class="personBtn" id="obj4" ></div>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="righty"></div>                     
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#home .droppable {
    position: absolute;
    width: 846px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 27px;
  }

#home .scroll_carrossel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: visible;
}

#home .scroll_carrossel .nav-container{
    width: 3384px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; 
}

#home .scroll_carrossel .nav-container .personBtn{
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* for each element */
#home .scroll_carrossel .nav-container #obj1.personBtn  {
    background-image: url(img/objetos/obj1.png);
    background-size: contain; 
    transform-origin: top left; 
    transform: scale(0.2);
} 
/* and so on... */

#home .scroll_carrossel .nav-container .personBtn.dropping{
    -webkit-animation: dropping 0.5s ease-out forwards;
    animation: dropping 0.5s ease-out forwards;
    transform-origin: center center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dropping {   
    100%{transform: scale(1);}
}
@keyframes dropping {   
    100%{transform: scale(1);}
}

#home .scroll_carrossel .nav-container .personBtn.backing{
    -webkit-animation: backing 0.5s ease-out forwards;
    animation: backing 0.5s ease-out forwards;
    transform-origin: top left;
}
@-webkit-keyframes backing {
    100%{transform: scale(0.17);}
}
@keyframes backing {
    100%{transform: scale(0.17);}
}
```

How is it possible to scroll the bottom bar (and all elements positioned inside it) without interfering with the position of the element already dropped in the area above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach your draggable element to your droppable container:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    $('.personBtn.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('dropping').css("z-index", 0);  
    $(this).append(ui);
}
```